# How to map the correct language in Qt multiple language supports?

Tags: c++, qt, localization

I need to add multiple languages to our Qt-based products. I did some googles and got some ideas. But, I could not find one answer: How does the '.ts' file know which language is for?

For examples, in the sample project: i18n.

I deleted the original 'i18n_zh.ts' file and used 'lupdate' to create a new 'i18n_zh.ts' file. I then looked at the contents of the new file. It has this line:

```
TS version="2.1" language="zh_CN"
```

I then used 'linguist' tool to open the new 'i18n_zh.ts' file and found out Qt knew it was Chinese translation.

How did Qt know it is Chinese? Where is the mapping table? Does '_zh' in the file name hint anything?

Some contents in the new 'i18n_zh.ts' file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="zh_CN">
<context>
<name>MainWindow</name>
<message>
    <location filename="../languagechooser.cpp" line="176"/>
    <location filename="../mainwindow.cpp" line="85"/>
    <source>English</source>
    <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
</message>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, `lupdate` parses the name file to get the language. It uses a similar method to the one by [`QLocale`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#QLocale-1).

Once you have the locale, you can use methods like [`QLocale::nativeLanguageName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#nativeLanguageName) to get the language name (in this case the language name in that language).

Just for completeness, `QTranslator` also uses such filename suffixes to find the correct .qm file to load for current locale. More info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load).

For additional information, a good start point is the own [Qt's wiki page about multi-language applications](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application).